# Allocating untagged counts to other tags

Tags: r, dplyr, data-wrangling

I have a quite long table that looks like this:

```r
library(tidyverse)
x=structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), loc = c("A", "B", "?", "A", "B", "?"), count1 = c(10L, 20L, 50L, 5L, 22L, 10L), count2 = c(324L, 564L, 121L, 87L, 66L, 445L)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
x
#> # A tibble: 6 x 4
#>      id loc   count1 count2
#>   <int> <chr>  <int>  <int>
#> 1     1 A         10    324
#> 2     1 B         20    564
#> 3     1 ?         50    121
#> 4     2 A          5     87
#> 5     2 B         22     66
#> 6     2 ?         10    445
```

For each id, I would like to dispatch counts where `loc` is unknown uniformly to loc A and loc B.

For instance, for `id==1` and column `count1`, loc A represent 1/3 of the total, therefore 1/3 of 50 is allocated to group A and 2/3 of 50 is allocated to group B, which would end on respectively 26.7 and 53.3. Rows with unknown `loc` should then be dropped.

There is (currently) no other possible value for `loc` than A, B or ?.

The ratio of A/A+B is different for every count and for every id.

I tried multiple ways of doing this, involving pivoting and transposing, but I never managed to achieve the intended result.

Here is the complete expected output:

```r
expected=structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), loc = c("A", "B", "A", "B"), count1 = c(26.67, 53.33, 6.85, 30.15), count2 = c(368.15, 640.85, 340.04, 257.96)), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

expected
#> # A tibble: 4 x 4
#>      id loc   count1 count2
#>   <int> <chr>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#> 1     1 A      26.7    368.
#> 2     1 B      53.3    641.
#> 3     2 A       6.85   340.
#> 4     2 B      30.2    258.

#Totals are obviously the same:
x %>% group_by(id) %>% summarise(across(count1:count2, sum))
#> # A tibble: 2 x 3
#>      id count1 count2
#>   <int>  <int>  <int>
#> 1     1     80   1009
#> 2     2     37    598
expected %>% group_by(id) %>% summarise(across(count1:count2, sum))
#> # A tibble: 2 x 3
#>      id count1 count2
#>   <int>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#> 1     1     80   1009
#> 2     2     37    598
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps this helps

```
library(dplyr)
x %>% 
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(across(starts_with('count'), ~ {
        tmp <- .
        i1 <- loc == '?'
        tmp[!i1] <- tmp[!i1] + tmp[!i1]/
       sum(tmp[!i1]) * tmp[i1] 
      tmp})) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  filter(loc != '?')
```

-ouptut

```
# A tibble: 4 x 4
     id loc   count1 count2
  <int> <chr>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1     1 A      26.7    368.
2     1 B      53.3    641.
3     2 A       6.85   340.
4     2 B      30.1    258.
```

Comment: This is even smarter after your edit! Thanks a lot, I could never have figured this out on my own!

Answer (score 2):

A bit verbose but will do the trick:

```
library(dplyr)

x %>% 
  filter(loc != "?") %>%
  left_join(x %>%
              filter(loc == "?"), by = "id") %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(across(ends_with(".x") & !contains("loc"), ~ prop.table(.x), .names = '{.col}_prop'),
         across(ends_with(".x") & !contains("loc"), ~ 
           get(gsub(".x", ".y", cur_column())) * get(paste(cur_column(), "_prop", sep = "")) + .x)) %>%
  select(1:4) %>%
  rename_with(~ gsub(".x", "", .), !id)

# A tibble: 4 x 4
# Groups:   id [2]
     id loc   count1 count2
  <int> <chr>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1     1 A      26.7    368.
2     1 B      53.3    641.
3     2 A       6.85   340.
4     2 B      30.1    258.
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an intutional solution with `data.table`

```r
library(data.table)
x=structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), loc = c("A", "B", "?", "A", "B", "?"), count1 = c(10L, 20L, 50L, 5L, 22L, 10L), count2 = c(324L, 564L, 121L, 87L, 66L, 445L)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
setDT(x)
x[,`:=`(count1 = as.double(count1),
        count2 = as.double(count2))]

x[,`:=`(count1 = fifelse(loc != "?", count1 + count1[3] * count1/(count1[1] + count1[2]), count1),
        count2 = fifelse(loc != "?", count2 + count2[3] * count2/(count2[1] + count2[2]), count2)),
      by=id][loc != "?"]
#>    id loc    count1   count2
#> 1:  1   A 26.666667 368.1486
#> 2:  1   B 53.333333 640.8514
#> 3:  2   A  6.851852 340.0392
#> 4:  2   B 30.148148 257.9608
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Very interesting, but I'd like better to not depend on `data.table`.